# Skype via car Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, skype, samsung-galaxy-s7

I just bought a Samsung Galaxy S7, bound it to my car's Bluetooth and able to make/accept regular calls. However I cannot figure out how to make calls from Skype through car's Bluetooth. When phone is connected to bluetooth and I make a Skype call - call goes through phone's speaker, not through Bluetooth.

Any advice on how to do it?

P.S. I was able to it with my old Windows Phone, so I believe it should be possible with Android 6

Comment: Try [SoundAbout](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.woodslink.android.wiredheadphoneroutingfix), it is well spoken of but don't know how it works with Skype. From app description *Route the phone call audio to (Built in Earpiece, External speaker, Bluetooth (mono), Wired Headphones, Wired Headset (with mic),..*

Comment: I have installed it and will test for a couple of days. Not the best solution,  as it does not work with car's call control buttons,  but at least I can talk via Bluetooth.

Comment: Hei, @beeshyams, your solution is currently the best. Although I still could not make my Android work with car's buttons. If you want: write your solution as an answer so I can mark it :)

Comment: Deleted my answer as that app is not available on Play Store

Answer (score 1):

Every time skype initiates a video call, it changes the default audio output.  This will turn off blutooth if you have turned it on.  You need to go back into settings and reenable your audio output every time you start a video chat in skype.

Comment: Well, I do not use video calls in car,  but even simple calls do not work via Bluetooth without additional "dancing" around android :(

Answer (score 1):

I connected phone via android auto and then audio gets routed properly to car audio

Answer (score 0):

Skype on Windows Phone more powerful than on Android, because they both Microsoft's products. On Android you cant make calls via skype from car's bluetooth. But can make call from phone and connect it via AUX and then sound will go throught car's speakers

Comment: As much as I have Google for the moment: it seems like a huge android fragmentation bothers.  Skype+Bluetooth works on some phones and doesn't on others. I just really thought it would work on S7. I don't think Microsoft makes it worse just because it is Android. Android's market share is huge, so it would be stupid to cut it off.

Comment: And after Windows Phone I really hate SwiftKey - it keeps replacing everything I type. I meant: as much so I have googled...